# How to query and find out the name and version of maven packages from bazel?

Tags: bazel

If I run this command with `grep`, I can retrieve a list of dependencies that my project needs from a maven repository.

```
bazel query "deps(//my-project-server)" | grep "@maven"
```

I will get a list of output like the following per dependency:

```
@maven//:com_thoughtworks_paranamer_paranamer
@maven//:v1/https/repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.8/paranamer-2.8.jar
@maven//:com_thoughtworks_paranamer_paranamer_2_8_extension
@maven//:v1/https/repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.8/paranamer-2.8-sources.jar
```

What I actually want is the name of the package and the version.

In the example above I want to extract this pair of data `com_thoughtworks_paranamer_paranamer` and `2.8`.

Is there a direct way that I can use to ask bazel to product such results for all the maven dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

`bazel query <expression> --output=build | grep tags` could get you pretty far:

For example:

```
$ bazel query @maven//:all --output=build | grep tags
  tags = ["maven_coordinates=org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:2.1"],
  tags = ["maven_coordinates=org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.1"],
  tags = ["maven_coordinates=com.google.guava:guava:27.0-jre"],
  tags = ["maven_coordinates=org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.17"],
  tags = ["maven_coordinates=org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.5.2"],
  tags = ["maven_coordinates=com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1"],
  tags = ["maven_coordinates=com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava"],
  tags = ["maven_coordinates=com.google.guava:failureaccess:1.0"],
  tags = ["maven_coordinates=com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.2.0"],
  tags = ["maven_coordinates=com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2"],
```